# "Внимание(:) вопрос"

Tags: пунктуация

"А теперь внимание(:) вопрос..." — говорит ведущий "Что? Где? Когда?" Я бы поставил тут двоеточие, а как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"А теперь внимание, вопрос..." — говорит ведущий "Что? Где? Когда?"   Это бессоюзное сложное предложение, где первое и второе предложения эллиптические, двоеточие было бы,если б второе заключало в себе причину или раскрывало смысл первого, но здесь значение следующее: А теперь обратите внимание(сосредоточьтесь), далее следует вопрос... Хотя иногда ставят и двоеточие:  А теперь внимание (почему?): (потому что дальше будет)вопрос. Или: Внимание: дети! Но конструкция с запятой проще и употребляется чаще.